# meta-data related to the current buffer

Tags: buffers, files, microsoft-windows, time-date

How can I retrieve the date/time of the creation of the current file (`file-date-time-of-creation`) on my system?
The same question can arise for the size.

A related question was asked [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7888/2609).  This is a Windows related question, but the question also arises for other OS's.

Comment: You can bind a key to a function that does `(message "%s" (your-fn-that-returns-the-file-date-time-of-creation))`. Also a question I have is if you want to do this only for buffers containing files or even for non-file buffers like \*scratch\*.

Comment: @kaushalmodi Of course. Thanks. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the file last-modified date/time, the file last-accessed date/time, and the file last-status-change date/time, use function `file-attributes`. See the Elisp manual, node [`File Attibutes`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html).

(It's not very clear what you are asking. You mention the date of the **buffer** creation, but @kaushalmodi mentions the "file-date-time-of-creation" in a comment and you seem to go along with that comment. Just what date/time are you asking about? If this is about the file, as I'm guessing, then please edit the question title and body to reflect that.)

Comment: Also on unix systems, I believe that the file last-status-change is the closest we can get to the file creation time. Not sure if the same will work on Windows (I have no way of testing that).

Comment: I edited the question. Is `last-status-change` the same as `file-date-time-of-creation`? If this is the case, this answers the question. `File Attibutes` has a list of 11 elements. I cannot explicitly find `file-date-time-of-creation`.

Comment: No, I don't think that `file-attributes` gives you the time of the file creation. Thanks for editing your question to make clear that that is what you want: file creation time. I can delete this answer, as it does not give you that, but I will leave it up for a bit, in case it helps someone.